# Undefined property: Mandrill::$messages

Tags: php, mandrill

I am using **mandrill API** but getting `error:Undefined property: Mandrill::$messages.code:`

```
  $mandrill = new Mandrill('My KEY');        
    $message = array(
        'subject' => 'My subject',
        'from_email' => 'marc@example.com',
        'to' => array(array('email' => 'recipient1@example.com', 'name'=> 'Marc')),
        'merge_vars' => array(array(
            'rcpt' => 'recipient1@example.com',
            'vars' =>
            array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'FIRSTNAME',
                    'content' => 'Recipient 1 first name'),
                array(
                    'name' => 'LASTNAME',
                    'content' => 'Last name')
        ))));

    $template_name = 'Lodging Connection';

    $template_content = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'main',
            'content' => 'Hi *|FIRSTNAME|* *|LASTNAME|*, thanks for signing up.'),
        array(
            'name' => 'footer',
            'content' => 'Copyright 2013.')

    );        
    $response = $mandrill->messages->send($template_name, $template_content, $message);
    print_r($response);
```

Comment: Is `$message = array()` not supposed to be `$messages = array()`? Or change `$mandrill->messages->send()` to `$mandrill->message->send()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending messages with template you should use [`sendTemplate`](https://www.mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html#method=send-template) instead of `send`:

```
$response = $mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message);
```

Comment: thnxs this worked for me but how can I add content in my template by api?

Comment: Try [these](https://www.mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.php.html#method=update) functions. If you are still stuck try asking it as a separate question.